# PrimeNG - options are not showing properly when using p-dropdown inside a p-dialog

Tags: angular, primeng

This a my code for dropdown. I have used this in a p-dialog tag.

```
<p-dropdown [options]="mappingField"></p-dropdown>
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If mappingField is an object array you should add optionLabel="name" instead name you should write the value that you want to see in the dropdown,
Example:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" optionLabel="name"></p-dropdown>
```

The cities array:

```
this.cities = [
    {name: 'New York', code: 'NY'},
    {name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'},
    {name: 'London', code: 'LDN'},
    {name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST'},
    {name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'}
];
```